# Anyone using sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert to update Files (ContentDocument/ContentVersion)?

Tags: salesforcedx, files, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink, fileupload

I have some small place-keeper files (ContentDocument/ContentVersion) loaded by some existing code but want to replace the content with the actual PDF/Video data. This is to pre-load scratch orgs with some standard data that totals maybe 50 Mbytes spread across 20 files.

Does anyone have that working using e.g.:

```
sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert
```

with the binary data as base 64 in the CSV or the JSON equivalent? Or is there a better mechanism to use for this task of updating Salesforce Files?

**PS**

Just read in the [Bulk API Developer Guide](https://blog.bessereau.eu/assets/pdfs/api_asynch.pdf) that:

> Currently base64 fields are not supported in queries with the Bulk
> API.

Does that suggest base64 does work in updates?

Comment: How does Bulk API not supporting base64 fields in a query hurt your chances of upserting the document?

Comment: Hi @identigral it doesn't was just suggesting that it implies that the upsert of base64 _will_ work. But wondering about whether multiple MBytes are handled by this API and its SFDX wrappers?

Comment: You may have a look at SFDX Data Move Utility, it can handle File and Attachment, so maybe it works with ContentVersion. https://help.sfdmu.com/key-features

Comment: Thanks @NicolasVuillamy - helpful.